# import error: './App' does not contain a default export (imported as 'App')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I´m trying to replicate the demo of this library: https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

To automate the creation of forms, specifically, I'm trying with this example:

[image]

For that I'm following these steps:

1) Create a project using: npm init react-app formapp
2) Install de dependencies: yarn add react-jsonschema-form

Just after this step, if I run the app as: npm start

It works and I get:

[image]

3) I'm overwriting app.Js with the code:

```
import React from "react";
import Form from "react-jsonschema-form";

const Form = JSONSchemaForm.default;
const schema = {
  title: "Todo",
  type: "object",
  required: ["title"],
  properties: {
    title: {type: "string", title: "Title", default: "A new task"},
    done: {type: "boolean", title: "Done?", default: false}
  }
};

const log = (type) => console.log.bind(console, type);

ReactDOM.render((
  <Form schema={schema}
        onChange={log("changed")}
        onSubmit={log("submitted")}
        onError={log("errors")} />
), document.getElementById("app"));
```

Now I when I try to start the app I get this error:

```
Failed to compile
./src/App.js
  Line 4:7:  Parsing error: Identifier 'Form' has already been declared

  2 | import Form from "react-jsonschema-form";
  3 | 
> 4 | const Form = JSONSchemaForm.default;
    |       ^
  5 | const schema = {
  6 |   title: "Todo",
  7 |   type: "object",
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.
```

So I commented line number four:

```
import React from "react";
import Form from "react-jsonschema-form";

//const Form = JSONSchemaForm.default;
const schema = {
  title: "Todo",
  type: "object",
```

And tried again, then I got this other error:

```
Failed to compile
./src/index.js
Attempted import error: './App' does not contain a default export (imported as 'App').
```

EDIT:

This is the code of the index file I'm using:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: can you provide your index.js? It looks like you imported the above script there trough something like import App from './app.js'; am I right? but you don't export App from your app.js

Comment: @BastianFießinger Just added it

Answer (score 0):

```
  2 | import Form from "react-jsonschema-form"; // makes a variable "Form"
  3 | 
  4 | const Form = JSONSchemaForm.default; // so this is already declared on line 2
```

You need to change ether line 2 or 4 from `Form` to `somethingOtherThanForm`

Answer (score 0):

Like already mentioned by [MrPickles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62469375/4445399) you can get rid of the naming issue by folloiwing his instructions.

For the other error the problem is that you don't export anything in your app.js.

```js
import App from './App'; // App or Default is not exported by App.js
```

Also you don't have a `HTMLElement` with the ID of `app` in your DOM.

```js
import React from "react";
import Form from "react-jsonschema-form";

const Form = JSONSchemaForm.default;
const schema = {
  title: "Todo",
  type: "object",
  required: ["title"],
  properties: {
    title: {type: "string", title: "Title", default: "A new task"},
    done: {type: "boolean", title: "Done?", default: false}
  }
};

const log = (type) => console.log.bind(console, type);

// Export App
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Form schema={schema}
        onChange={log("changed")}
        onSubmit={log("submitted")}
        onError={log("errors")} />
  );
}
```

Now in your index.js you can either do:

```js
import App from './App'; // Default export
```

or

```js
import { App } from './App'; // named export
```